# Incrementing an array position

Tags: javascript

Considering I have this array:

```
var myArr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

How is it possible to increment the 3rd '0' in the array by 1?

Comment: try doing myArr[2] += 1;

Comment: maybe `myArr[2] = myArr[2] + 1;` ?

Comment: I know it looks ridiculous but I wrote a big jumble of code and I wanted to see other solutions than the obvious ones

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides can you show your actual solution? maybe it will help understand your question, because other than the *obivous ones* it's hard to imagin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myArr[2]++;
```

Arrays are zero-indexed. So, the 3rd element is at key `2`.

`++` is JavaScript's [increment operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_(.2B.2B)) Which does as much as *"add `1` to it's operand."*

Answer (score 1):

```
myArr[2] = myArr[2] + 1;
```

The first index in an array is 0, so index 2 would be the third zero.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn it into a function so you can increment any index you want at any time:

```
var myArr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var increment = function (i) {
    myArr[i] += 1;
}

increment(2);
```

Comment: why the downvote? I like 'utility' functions although this is pretty...err..not needed

Comment: This is _very_ redundant. Besides, what if you want to increment a value in a different array? Write an extra function? Add the array as parameter? Just use `myArr[x]++;`. This really doesn't need a function.

Comment: It's unnecessary. Do you write functions for concatenating strings as well?

Comment: If I was concatenating a string the same way in multiple locations yes. I would.

Comment: On second thought you got me, I would do the same